# How to use CloudFront with ELB for http to https redirection

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have implemented AWS ELB for SSL. It's working fine with my domain. I want to redirect http to https. So I used the CloudFront for it. But after implementing the cloudfront, I didn't get success.

For implementing the Cloudfront, I am using the default SSL because there is no certificate in `region=us-east-1`. I have updated the CNames in Route53.

For generating the certificate under ELB I have opted global.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the solution after 10 days after a lots of R&D.

**Http to https redirection using CloudFront**

**Follow below steps:**

1. Login into your aws console and search CloudFront
2. Go to CloudFront: Create Distribution(please select **Web distribution**)
3. Under **Origin Settings** : Select the Origin Domain Name (you can assign the IP is instance/You can opt the ELB/You can select the S3 bucket)
4. Under **Default Cache Behavior Settings** : Select Viewer Protocol Policy: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
5. **Under Object Caching**: opt customize (Remain default setting in Minimum TTL , Maximum TTL and Default TTL)
6. **Forward Cookies** : All
7. **Query String Forwarding and Caching** : All
8. **Distribution Settings** :
   Select **Price Class**:  (Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)).
9. **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)s**: add all domain names that you want to be directed at this Distribution
10. **SSL Certificate** : Under SSL you can opt defaut or your custom certificate that depends upon your requirement.(here I am opting custom certificate.)

**Note** : For Custom SSL Certificate (certificate should be in `us-east-1 region`).

**Final Step:**

11. Once the Distribution has been created (can took 15 to 20 minutes)
12. Update your DNS CNAME to point to the ___.cloudfront.net address under **Route 53**.

Still you getting problem please let me know

Comment: Hey I have used Elastic Beanstalk and currently the CNAME is pointing to the EBS ... you said point that to cloudfront in step 12. But then for Origin Settings  ( 3rd point ) I still select the Elastic Load Balancer ?

Comment: If you are using Route 53 for redirection then here we have 2 options to redirect the traffic to https
1. Under CNAME in Hosted Zone you have to mentioned the cloudfront.net address which comes when we successfully created the EBS.
2 Change the a record from IP/ElasticLoadBalancer to CloudFront Url